# Displaying a target area / value on a HighCharts graph

Tags: highcharts

I wish to use HighCharts to display a (variable) target value on a graph, like in the image. I cannot find any built-in feature in HighCharts to do this. Am I overlooking anything, or will I have to use the Renderer? In that case, I guess I would need to retrieve the coordinates of the left and right sides of the chart area, and the coordinates corresponding to a given Y axis value. Is this possible, and if so, how?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYsaO.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [plot bands](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#axis-object).

For example:

```
chart.addPlotBand({
    id: 'target',
    from: 90,
    to: 100
});
```

To make it dynamic, you would just need to call `chart.removePlotBand('target')`, then add your new target.